# How to add circular images as an lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, css, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system

I have to add a circular image in my lightning component. 
I know we can do this by using slds-avatar.

I tried to do it but my image is displaing in ovel shape.
I think I am not able to give radius so that I can make is circular.

Also I want to add an outer circle to my image which is exactly half you can see it in the attached image.
How will the circuler and outer half circle be achived by using lightning css.

[image]

```
<aura:component><span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar--circle image__crop--1x1 slds-avatar--x-large"  >
        <img src="{!concat('/servlet/servlet.FileDownload?file=',v.cont.Pic_Photo_Id__c)}" alt="person name" />
    </span><br/><br/></aura:component>
```

This is the image I am using 
[image]

Comment: Please post your code.So that we can help

Answer (score 1):

you need to set the width and height of the image to override the slds's image css.

**ImageApp.app**

```
<aura:application >
     <ltng:require styles="/resource/SLDS202/assets/styles/salesforce-lightning-design-system.css"/>
    <div class="slds">
            <span class="slds-avatar slds-avatar--circle">
                <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/RJACY.jpg" alt="person name" class="imgCls"/>
        </span>
    </div>
</aura:application>
```

**ImageApp.css**

```
.THIS .imgCls{
    width:114px;
    height:113px;
}
```

Comment: This will not respect the ratio of the image which might be distorted depending of the initial ratio.

Answer (score 1):

**border-radius: 50%;**

```
.THIS .profileIcon {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    vertical-align: middle;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    vertical-align: middle;
    border: 0;

    color: #ffffff;
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: This will not respect the ratio of the image which might be distorted depending of the initial ratio.